# Bootstrap 3 Make Custom Navigation Menu Responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar

I am currently converting a psd to html using bootstrap. And I want to make use of the bootstrap responsive menu.

But I don't want to use the bootstrap menu for non-mobile devices such that, if the user is on the mobile he'll bootstrap's responsive menu and if he's using a desktop or any other md sized device in bootstrap then he should see my navigation menu which I styles on my own. How would I do this?

My Html Markup for the menu:

```
<div id="navigation" class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="selected">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Archive</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other Pages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav> <!-- end nav -->
</div>
```

Comment: if you are aware of css specificity than its not a problem ; just write your css for navigation after bootstrap css it will override bootstrap css

Comment: But how I will force it to be used only when the device is not mobile?

Comment: you can write css in media query , boot strap provide media query the are using

Comment: you mean using media="mobile" when referencing stylesheets?

Comment: also bootstrap uses mobile first approach so you can also write different nav for mobile and non-mobile by using class like col-xm

Comment: yes you can do by that too

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly easy task.

You need to know two things.
1. Media Queries
2. Bootstrap view-port break points

Link for break points

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Link for media queries

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Using that you can set specific CSS for Desktops, Mobile devices, etc...